# How to define a simple bijection between the set of all permutations of {0,1,...,n} and the set {x | x is natural, x < (n+1)!}

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

I am working on a programming assignment and I need to solve this mathematical problem in order to marginally improve the time complexity of my code. What I need is a simple way to pair each permutation of the numbers {0,1,...,n} with a corresponding natural number between 0 and n!.

Here is a simple example of what I'm looking for with n = 1. (n+1)! = 2! = 2. Therefore we want to biject the permutations of {0,1} with the set {0,1} (1 is the last number less than 2!). A simple solution is as follows:

(0,1) -> 0
(1,0) -> 1

For n = 2, (n+1)! = 3! = 6, we want to biject the permutations of {0,1,2} with {0,1,2,3,4,5}. We can construct something like:

(0,1,2) -> 0
(1,0,2) -> 1
(0,2,1) -> 2
(2,0,1) -> 3
(2,1,0) -> 4
(1,2,0) -> 5

or,

(0,1,2) -> 2
(1,0,2) -> 1
(0,2,1) -> 4
(2,0,1) -> 3
(2,1,0) -> 5
(1,2,0) -> 0

Both would work just as well.

It is irrelevant which number gets paired to every permutation. What I need is a way to define a function, preferably in a simple algebraic way (although recursion would also work), which, given a permutation, calculates its unique corresponding number in a simple and elegant way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Combine [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) with [factorial base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you elaborate on what you mean exactly when you suggest that I 'combine' them?

Comment: If you are working in Python, I suggest you use itertools.

Comment: The [Stack  Overflow question 7918978](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7918806) "Finding n-th permutation without computing others" has an answer that gives algorithms "that converts from a rank to a permutation, and one that does the inverse."